# What is this output in GDB, and how do I make it stop?

Tags: gdb

I have been following this tutorial:  https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial

There is a "make debug" setup that will start a qemu instance and then connect gdb to it remotely.  I can get all of this to work fine. But while the OS is running, gdb is constantly printing out these messages to the console:

```
  2288: v=20 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00001005 pc=00001005 SP=0010:0008fff8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000
EAX=00000000 EBX=00007d79 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000068
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00090000 ESP=0008fff8
EIP=00001005 EFL=00000206 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007ccd 00000017
IDT=     000036a0 000007ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=0008ffec CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
  2289: v=21 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00001005 pc=00001005 SP=0010:0008fff8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000
EAX=00000000 EBX=00007d79 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000068
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00090000 ESP=0008fff8
EIP=00001005 EFL=00000206 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007ccd 00000017
IDT=     000036a0 000007ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=0008ffec CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
```

There are 2 of these messages pasted above (starts with "2288" & "2289") -- but I'm pretty sure they probably started at 1.  These make it so you can't actually do anything useful in gdb unless I go and pause the qemu window.

What are these messages from, and is there any way to get them to stop?

Comment: I don't think this output is coming from GDB, I suspect this is most likely from QEMU.  This is based on register names being upper case, GDB prefers lower case, and strings like R_EAX don't appear anywhere in GDB's source code.

Comment: @Andrew You are absolutely correct -- I just tried running qemu and gdb from different terminals and the messages appear in the qemu one.  The command line for qemu was qemu-system-i386 -s -S -fda os-image.bin -d guest_errors,int, and that last argument ("-d int") is to print information about interrupts.  Those are the timer interrupts occurring.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's comment was correct.  The QEMU command line arguments "-d guest_errors,int" were causing debugging information to be printed out in the console.